# Having trouble selecting elements in jQuery with JS added on the form

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a form with a file element and a button.  When I click the button it is supposed to run some JS.  I have tried three separate ways to get this to work but each way gives me a different result.

The first way actually works.  The problem, though, is obvious.  I do not want inline JS here.  It's messy and annoying to work with.

**Method 1:** Inline JS; Works but is awful.

```
function carousel_npd_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['carousel_data']['add_slide_button'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#name' => 'carousel_add_slide',
      '#value' => t('Add Slide'),
      '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'onclick' => 'javascript:
          event.preventDefault();
          alert(\'test\'); // escape EVERY single quote.  This method is no good.
        ',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Method 2:** Adding the JS file to the #attached property of the form array; JS included in the page source, but, from what I can tell, before the form is loaded in the DOM, so the button click function is ineffective.

Form:

```
function carousel_npd_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['carousel_data']['add_slide_button'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#name' => 'carousel_add_slide',
      '#id' => 'add-slide-button',
      '#value' => t('Add Slide'),
      '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
    );
    // Using 'attached' shows the .js file is added in the source, but when I
    // click the button it submits, ignore preventDefault, and no alert.
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'carousel_npd') . '/add_slide.js';
    $form['#validate'][] = 'carousel_npd_carousel_data_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'carousel_npd_carousel_data_submit';
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var c = 0;
(function ($) {
  $('#add-slide-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
    console.log(c);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

**Method 3:** Using the '#after_build' property to run a function to add the JS to the page after the form is loaded into the DOM; The form refuses to load.  The rest of Drupal loads fine, just not the form.

PHP:

```
function carousel_npd_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    $form['carousel_data']['add_slide_button'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#name' => 'carousel_add_slide',
      '#id' => 'add-slide-button',
      '#value' => t('Add Slide'),
      '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['#after_build'][] = 'carousel_npd_add_slide';
    $form['#validate'][] = 'carousel_npd_carousel_data_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'carousel_npd_carousel_data_submit';

  }
}

function carousel_npd_add_slide() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'carousel_npd') . '/add_slide.js');
}
```

JS:

```
var c = 0;
(function ($) {
  $('#add-slide-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
    console.log(c);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I think method 3 would be the most appropriate, but it's the one that causes the form to not load at all.  As soon as I uncomment the '#after_build' property the form loads without an issue.  I should not that it's important that jQuery is available for this JS code, hence the jQuery wrappers in the JS file.  In the inline method, I have to use *(jQuery)* in place of every *$*, which is another downside to using that method in addition to escaping every single quote.

Comment: Have you looked into Drupal behaviors?

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein - I use it elsewhere in the module, but this is a simple button click.  As a temporary fix I just stuck it in a hook_init() and set the file scope to footer.  It's solved the problem temporarily but I would like to not use hook_init().

Comment: What I would really like is for that third method to work.  I can't figure out why it's causing the form to not load at all.  Nothing in syslog or apache error log either.

Comment: Try to use behaviours in your javascript: https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors. Let me know if this fixes the problem :)